# UITableView: scrollViewDidScroll executes and contentOffset jumps when gestureRecognizers active

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, ios11

When using `gestureRecognizers` (`UIPanGestureRecognizer` and `UITapGestureRecognizer`) on top of a `UITableView` (in a `ViewController`) in iOS 11 (Xcode 9.0, Swift 4), the function `scrollViewDidScroll` automatically executes even when tapping or panning to left/right (without the `tableView` actually scrolling) and the `contentOffset` jumps (by -140 on iPhone X and by -116 on iPhone 8) for a short period of time, then it returns to normal. The `contentOffset` jump is not visible in the UI, but it is printable in the console. (and launches an animation, that I have associated with a certain offset). Disabling the `gestureRecognizers` fixes the problem, but I need them for other gestures than scrolling up and down (e.g. tapping, panning to left/right, ...)

This problem does not occur on older firmware (Tested on iOS 10.3.1). Neither does the `scrollViewDidScroll` function execute, nor does the `contentOffset` change.

I'd be very thankful for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that disabling the option `Adjust Scroll View Insets` (in IB or in Code), even though marked as the right answer on some similar posts, is only part of the equation.

Some constraints were not set properly on the `UITableView` and that caused the bug.
Getting all the constraints right (or deleting them completely) and disabling the aforementioned option fixed it for me.